# Wpf binding Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following Code in a `Style` for `TreeViewItems` in a Resource file:

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Name="img"
                   Width="20"
                   Height="20"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   Source=""/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

How can I now set the image/source for a `TreeViewItem` in code?

Comment: is it MVVM application? or  code of behind window?

Comment: I mean the C#-Code behind a wpf application.

Comment: Is the Image always the same? Or is it depending on the treeviewitem?

Comment: Depends on the Treeviewitem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewWpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="treeView">
        </TreeView>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateTree();
        }

        private void CreateTree()
        {
            treeView.Items.Add(GetTreeView("text"));
        }

        private TreeViewItem GetTreeView(string text)
        {
            TreeViewItem newTreeViewItem = new TreeViewItem();

            // create stack panel
            StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
            stack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            // create Image
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/YourImage.png", UriKind.Relative));

            // Label
            TextBlock lbl = new TextBlock();
            lbl.Text = text;
            lbl.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            lbl.Width = 139;

            // Add into stack
            stack.Children.Add(image);
            stack.Children.Add(lbl);

            // assign stack to header
            newTreeViewItem.Header = stack;

            return newTreeViewItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention that `image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/YourImage.png", UriKind.Relative))` where "/Images/" - name of folder.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I make the Item expandable? Edit: Nvm I just didnt add a subitem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MyNameIsHans you can accept my reply as an answer if it helps to you:).

Comment: Who downvoted this answer? It works totally fine for me.

Comment: I do not know. A downvoter has not said anything. It is really weird.